# .htaccess strange Redirect behaviour

Tags: .htaccess

I have following .htaccess (domain names have been changed and file shortened):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

Redirect 302 / https://www.destination.com/software/pwa
Redirect 302 /cases https://www.destination.com/cases
Redirect 302 /cases/digitaal-meldpunt-voor https://www.destination.com/cases/ontwikkeling
```

When I visit https://www.example.com, I am redirected properly to https://www.destination.com/software/pwa. But when I visit https://www.example.com/cases, I am being redirected to https://www.destination.com/software/pwacases.

Looks like the first rule is interfering with the others and I have no clue why, Google says that this should be working properly.

If I rewrite the .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(|/)$ https://www.destination.com/software/pwa [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^cases(|/)$ https://www.destination.com/cases [R=302,L]
```

Both redirects are working properly. Why doesn't the first .htaccess work as intended?

Comment: The `Redirect` directive does prefix-based matching on the path, and appends any excess to the target URL. The documentation clearly explains this …

Comment: From what I read online, the `Redirect` is a full match based redirect, meaning if route /cases exists, it will match against it and nothing else ... But your comment did give me a tip and I reversed the order of redirects, now they are working as intended.

Comment: Don’t know what you read and where, but [the manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) is explicitly clear about this: _“[…] any request **beginning with** URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path** will be **appended to the target URL**.”_ Which in this case means, even if you put your redirect for `/` last, this would still redirect a request for `/foobar` to `https://www.destination.com/software/pwafoobar` now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Redirect 302 / https://www.destination.com/software/pwa
> Redirect 302 /cases https://www.destination.com/cases
> Redirect 302 /cases/digitaal-meldpunt-voor https://www.destination.com/cases/ontwikkeling
> ```

As noted in comments, the mod_alias `Redirect` directive uses simple prefix-matching, and everything after the match is appended to the end of the target URL. So, the first redirect above matches *everything* and everything after the initial slash is appended to the end of the target URL - which is what you are seeing.

To resolve this you can reorder the `Redirect` directives so the most specific is first.

Or, you could use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` instead which matches against a regex (like the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule`), rather than simple prefix-matching.

For example:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ https://www.destination.com/software/pwa
RedirectMatch 302 ^/cases$ https://www.destination.com/cases
RedirectMatch 302 ^/cases/digitaal-meldpunt-voor$ https://www.destination.com/cases/ontwikkeling
```

Which matches only the URLs `/`, `/cases` or `/cases/digitaal-meldpunt-voor` exactly.

Note that in your `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) directives you have also allowed for an optional trailing slash? The `Redirect` directives would also have allowed for an optional trailing slash because they are prefix-matching.

---

It is the prefix-matching nature of the `Redirect` directive that allows you to easily mass-redirect everything from one domain to another whilst maintaining the URL-path:

```
Redirect / https://newdomain.example/
```

Comment: I will accept your answer since it's the most informative and I actually did as you suggested, re-arrange the `Redirect` rules, so that the / rule was last. And it's working as intended.
I didn't opt for `RewriteRule` or `RewriteMatch` since I achieved what I wanted and it also works with trailing slashes.